# How to delete a Jenkins Workflow build that crashed and is endlessly running?

Tags: jenkins, crash, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-workflow

In some occasions a runtime error causes a Jenkins Workflow build to crash, but Jenkins still sees this as a running build. Aborting the job is not possible in de Jenkins Gui. How can I abort or delete such a build?

Answer (score 0):

I restart jenkins. I'm not happy with it though.

Comment: Restarting Jenkins doesn't work. The zombie jobs survive a restart :)

Answer (score 0):

You can disconnect a slave node even when it's running a build. Once you reconnect the slave, there should be no jobs running on it.

Comment: And if the job is running on the master node?

Comment: I read the below comment that the build still survives after restart on the master. You might have luck going into your Jenkins directory (which you can find under Manage Jenkins>Configure System), then go into the jenkins/jobs/[jobname]/builds/ directory, and try removing the build that's running manually. Both the directory and the link.

Comment: I did try to remove the directory, maybe I forgot the link. I'll try this again.

Answer (score 0):

See [JENKINS-25550](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25550) for the current workaround for this class of bug.